# For loop in activity diagram

Tags: algorithm, loops, for-loop, activity-diagram

I'm have written a pseudo code for an algorithm and I would like to draw an activity diagram for it. However, I cannot find any source stating which notation to use for "for loops". I don't suppose it is the decision diamond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there is special [loop task notation](http://camunda.org/bpmn/reference/#activities-task) in `BPMN`, there is **no special notation** for loops in `UML` Activity Diagrams. The things to use are: `decision node` and `guard condition`

See also:

- [uml-diagrams.org: UML Activity Diagrams Reference](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams-reference.html)

Answer (score 2):

There is an example.

```
int[] ns = { 1, 4, 9, 16, 25 };
for (int i=0; i<ns.length; i++) {
    int n = ns[i];
    System.out.println(n);
}
```

[image]

```
@startuml
start
:int[] ns = {1, 4, 9, 16, 25};
partition for {
    :int i=0;
    repeat :int n = ns[i];
      :System.out.println(n);
    backward:i++;
    repeat while (i<ns.length)
}
stop
@enduml
```